# need advise on sift feature - is there such thing as a good feature?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I am trying out vlfeat, got huge amount of features from an image database, and I am testing with the ground truth for mean average precision (MAp). Overall, I got roughly 40%. I see that some of the papers got higher MAp, while using techniques very similar to mine; the standard bag of word.

I am currently looking for an answer for obtaining higher MAp for the standard bag of word technique. While I see that there are other implementation such as SURF and what not, let's stick to the standard Lowe's SIFT and the standard bag of word in this question.

So the thing is this, I see that vl_sift got thresholding to allow you to be more strict on feature selection. Currently, I understand that going for higher threshold might net you smaller and more meaningful "good" features list, and possibly reduce some noisy features. **"Good" features mean, given the same images with different variation, very similar features are also detected on other images**.

However, how high should we go for this thresholding? Sometimes, I see that an image returns no features at all with higher threshold. At first, I was thinking of keep on adjusting the threshold, until I get better MAp. But again, I think it's a bad idea to keep on adjusting just to find the best MAp for the respective database. So my questions are:

1. While adjusting threshold may decrease numbers of features, does increasing threshold always return a lesser number yet better features?
2. Are there better approaches to obtain the good features?
3. What are other factors that can increase the rate of obtaining good features?

Comment: Irrelevant of what parametric method X you are using, it is relatively common to adjust the parameters like you say. But, the approach to do so is different from using the whole dataset like that. What you do is separate your data in training and test, then you adjust the parameters for your training data, and check how they work out for the training data. There are multiple ways on how this separation between training and test must be done in order to get accurate results, but this is all the basics of machine learning. Are you doing this form of separation ? It is not mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into some of the papers put out in response to the Pascal challenge in recent years. The impression they seem to give me is that standard 'feature detection' methods don't work very well with the Bag of Words technique. This makes sense when you think about it - BoW works by pulling together lots of weak, often unrelated features. It's less about detecting a specific object, but instead recognizing classes of objects and scenes. As such, putting too much emphasis on normal 'key features' can harm more than help.

As such, we see folks using *dense grids* and even random points as their features. From experience, using one of these methods over Harris corners, LoG, SIFT, MSER, or any of the like, has a great positive impact on performance.

To answer your questions directly:

1. Yes. From the [SIFT api](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html):

   > Keypoints are further refined by eliminating those that are likely to be unstable, either because they are selected nearby an image edge, rather than an image blob, or are found on image structures with low contrast. Filtering is controlled by the follow:
   >   **Peak threshold.** This is the minimum amount of contrast to accept a keypoint. It is set by configuring the SIFT filter object by vl_sift_set_peak_thresh().
   >   **Edge threshold.** This is the edge rejection threshold. It is set by configuring the SIFT filter object by vl_sift_set_edge_thresh().

   You can see examples of the two thresholds in action in the 'Detector parameters' section [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html).
2. Research suggests features densely selected from the scene yield more descriptive 'words' than those selected using more 'intelligent' methods (eg: SIFT, Harris, MSER). Try your Bag of Words pipeline with vl_feat's [DSIFT or PHOW](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/dsift.html) implementation. You should see a great improvement in performance (assuming your 'word' selection and classification steps are tuned well).
3. After a dense set of feature points, the biggest breakthrough in this field seems to have been the 'Spatial Pyramid' approach. This increases the number of words produced for an image, but provides a location aspect to the features - something inherently lacking in Bag of Words. After that, make sure your parameters are well tuned (which feature descriptor you're using (SIFT, HOG, SURF, etc), how many words are in your vocabulary, what classifier are you using ect.) Then.. you're in active research land. Enjoy =)

Comment: For number 1, yes, I am aware of such option, however, like I've said: **At first, I was thinking of keep on adjusting the threshold, until I get better MAp. But again, I think it's a bad idea to keep on adjusting just to find the best MAp for the respective database.** So like, are there better ways to do this or must I dive deep down into the abyss and hope that I will get a better result with many experiments? This takes time, you see.