# how to set threshold of vlfeat vl_ubcmatch function so that it gives good descriptor matches

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift, vlfeat

I am developing an application that calculates sift of images and matches the set of descritors using `vlfeat` functions `vl_sift` and `vl_ubcmatch`. After getting matches and scores it tells whether the two images are taken at **same location** or not i.e, if the two images are of Colosseum but with different scale and orientation the application tells that these are of same location.

The question is how should I set a threshold parameter in `vl_ubcmatch` so that I get best matched features and if I use adaptive threshold then what will be the relationship between matches, scores and number of descriptors.

I have already tried **peak and edge threshold** in `vl_sift` but not achieve good results. I am already following [need advice for good feature matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909630/need-advise-on-sift-feature-is-there-such-thing-as-a-good-feature)

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661051/how-does-vl-ubcmatch-work-technically) will help you.